# How to show photo album with arrangement from newest to oldest

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem when I use the below code to load the photo album out from the iphone. Although I loaded perfectly, the first photo appeared is the oldest photo. Is it possible to rearrange the order so that I can get the latest photo loaded first followed by time and oldest at the back?

```
- (IBAction)imageFromAlbum:(id)sender
  {    
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you will have to create custom photo picker of your own using asset library framework. depending on the ios version you are using you can use UICollectionViewController (ios6 onwards) or will have to create your own.

To get the all the photos/assets in the saved photos album, execute this method and then sort the objects using their creation date in descending order using property ALAssetPropertyDate

`thisVC.assetArray` will be the datasource for your custom table or collection view controller. These two methods are asynchronous, so you will need to refresh the tableView or collectionView once the datasource is complete

```
__block YourViewController *thisVC = self;
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            [self enumerateAssetForGroup:group forFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos] withCompletionBlock:^(id object) {
                thisVC.assetArray = object;
                [thisVC.assetArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                            NSDate *date1 = [obj1 valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                            NSDate *date2 = [obj2 valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

                            return ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending);
                 }];
                //in case of table
                [thisVC.tableView reloadData];
                //in case of collection view
                //reload collection view controller data
            }];
        }
    } failureBlock:nil];


- (void)enumerateAssetForGroup:(ALAssetsGroup*)group forFilter:(ALAssetsFilter*)filter withCompletionBlock:(ALAssetsEnumeration)enumerationCompletionBlock {

    [group setAssetsFilter:filter];
    __block NSInteger assetsCount = [group numberOfAssets];
    __block NSMutableArray *assetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (result) {
            [assetArray addObject:result];
            if (*stop) {
                enumerationCompletionBlock(assetArray);
                [assetArray release];
            }
        }
        else if (assetsCount == 0) {
            enumerationCompletionBlock(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

this part written in the first method will sort your array in descending order,

```
[thisVC.assetArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                NSDate *date1 = [obj1 valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                NSDate *date2 = [obj2 valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

                return ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending);
}];
```

Try this out if you really want to :)

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242935/how-to-obtain-the-original-file-name-of-the-image-picked-by-uiimagepickercontrol), you can get the actual filename of the image from the UIImagePicker. Since you seem to be able to access them in date order, a reverse enumeration of this result should sort your problem. Hope that helps...