# How do you get image file name from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm not getting the image name from photo library.
Anyone here knows a proper way to get image name?

Note: `PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)` this is deprecated.

Swift only

Thanks

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627901/how-to-get-file-name-in-uiimagepickercontroller-with-asset-library

May be help you.

Comment: @Jacky PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil) is deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain the original file name of the image picked by UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242935/how-to-obtain-the-original-file-name-of-the-image-picked-by-uiimagepickercontrol)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way

```
if let asset = info["UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset"] as? PHAsset{
            if let fileName = asset.value(forKey: "filename") as? String{
            print(fileName)
            }
        }
```

This will return you the actual file name in the photo library.

Comment: But it's not working in my case, asset always return nil.

Comment: Yes, now info doesn't provide "UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset" key.

Comment: you need to get photos permission before trying to access PhAsset info

Comment: How to get permission ? i have already added Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean the image file name? If so, this should help you. In your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL else { return }
    print(fileUrl.lastPathComponent)
}
```

Comment: lastPathComponent will return you the temp file name set by system

Comment: check my answer. This will return you the exact file name. I have checked the file name on mac also and its returning you the correct file name

Answer (score 6):

Update for iOS 12, Swift 4,

This will give you the file name and file extension directly

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL else { return }
    print(fileUrl.lastPathComponent) // get file Name
    print(fileUrl.pathExtension)     // get file extension
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine, kindly try the code before downvoting.

Comment: Just tried, this does not work for photo taken by camera :).

Answer (score 3):

Try with below code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
        if let fileName = (asset.value(forKey: "filename")) as? String {
          print(\(fileName))
        }
    }

    // Other Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset` is `nil` if you don't have granted permissions to access the photo library. The OS will not ask automatically and will still give you access to the file (I have no idea what's the logic behind this!) but the PHAsset is the info dictionary will be nil!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing is:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
  var imageName = "image_1"
  if let asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset, let fileName = asset.value(forKey: "filename") as? String {
    imageName = fileName
  } else if let url = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
    imageName = url.lastPathComponent
  }
}
```

`PHAsset` will be `nil` if the user hasn't given your app permissions to access library. This permission is no longer required if you use default `UIImagePickerController`, so if your app doesn't have them the OS will give you temporary access to a copy of the image, which all you can do is fall back to the path URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
        let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
        print(assetResources.first!.originalFilename)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```